# Where does Bazel store TenserFlow build?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build TensorFlow from sources following this guide: [Installing TensorFlow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources). The build seems to have worked fine, but then there's the last step:

> Invoke pip install to install that pip package. The filename of the
>   .whlfile depends on your platform. For example, the following command
>   will install the pip package for TensorFlow 1.0.0 on Linux:
>
> ```
> sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl
> ```

I suppose that's great if you run Linux, but I would have appreciated the location on Mac OS X as well.

Where is the package stored on Mac? I can't find it int `/tmp`, nor `/Users/Library/Caches`. And since search is broken on Mac, I'm out of luck.

Comment: Which package are you meaning, the one installed via `pip install`? If you installed that one as well then it would most likely be in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (that's normally where `pip` stores it's packages on `macOS / OS X`).

Comment: `find ~ -name 'tensorflow-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl'` should reveal the location. You may need to change the search location from `~` to `/tmp` or `/`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may have skipped a step. Bazel does not create this file. The program that Bazel builds does.

The prior step on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources to the one that you mention is to run

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

The second argument specified where to put the wheel file. Furthermore, that program logs its output directory:

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Mon Feb 20 22:08:08 EST 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /var/folders/yt/9r8s598x603bx58zq85yrx680096yv/T/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.gp5oIM0Z
Mon Feb 20 22:08:13 EST 2017 : === Building wheel
Mon Feb 20 22:08:45 EST 2017 : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
$ ls /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_12_intel.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure I use for building on MacOS

Pre-requisites

- Install Bazel
- Install CUDA 8.0
- Clone tensorflow into ~/git/tensorflow

Then

```
cd ~/git/tensorflow
git fetch --all
brew upgrade bazel

git stash
git rebase tf/master
git stash pop

# to resolve conflict from previous ./configure run
git checkout --theirs -- tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl

# do the actual build in TMUX session to avoid losing state when closing terminal
tmux new-session -s bazel -n 0
cd ~/git/tensorflow

./configure

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH

export date=feb11
export tag=head
export flags="--config=cuda --config=opt -k --action_env PATH --action_env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

bazel build $flags -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
rm -Rf /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
mkdir /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

mkdir -p ~/g/tfbins/$date.$tag
cp `find /tmp/tensorflow_pkg -type f ` ~/tfbins/$date.$tag
```

This will drop your wheel file into `~/tfbins/feb11.head`
You can automate `./configure` part by using something like
https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/configure_tf.sh

Note, CUDA building on MacOS is broken with latest Bazel release right now, you need to downgrade to 0.4.3 or build Bazel from head if you want CUDA -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7227

You can then share the wheel publicly by doing this (setup gsutil first and choose different $bucket)

```
export wheel=`find ~/tfbins/$date.$tag -type f`
export basename=`find ~/tfbins/$date.$tag -type f -printf "%f\n"`
cd ~/tfbins/$date.$tag
fullname=$date.$tag.$basename
ln -s $basename $fullname
export bucket=tensorflow-community-wheels
gsutil cp $fullname gs://$bucket
gsutil acl set public-read gs://$bucket/$fullname

echo https://storage.cloud.google.com/$bucket/$fullname
```

Then share the link printed from last line to https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels :)